# tensorflow pass numpy array to graph using placeholder vs tf.convert_to_tensor()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

If I understand correctly (no), there are two ways to pass a numpy array to a tensorflow computational graph:

1. use `tf.placeholder` and pass this numpy array in the `feed_dict`
2. use `tf.convert_to_tensor`, convert this numpy array as a tensor, then use this tensor for whatever calculation.

Are there any differences between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf_convert_to_tensor` is highly unpractical because it does not scale. See the example below:

```
X = np.random.rand(3,3)
Y = np.random.rand(3,3)
X_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
X_squared = tf.square(X_tensor)
Y_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y)
Y_squared = tf.square(Y)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = sess.run(X_squared)
    y = sess.run(Y_squared)
```

As you can see, for every Numpy array that we want to provide as input to the graph, we have to create a new `tf.convert_to_tensor` op. One example where this is fine is if you have a static input that won't change, then you have a single `tf.convert_to_tensor` op that you use. On the other hand, let's have a look at the same example using `tf.placeholder`:

```
X = np.random.rand(3,3)
Y = np.random.rand(3,3)
graph_input = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float64)
squared = tf.square(graph_input)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = sess.run(squared, feed_dict={graph_input: X})
    y = sess.run(squared, feed_dict={graph_input: Y})
```

As you can see, we use the `tf.placeholder` to dynamically provide input data to the graph. Consider it as a funnel, that you use to pour data in the graph. The `tf.placeholder` is fine for data that might/will change throughout the training such as learning rate, dropout probability, etc.

Comment: what if the inputs vary in shape: (?, 100) and (100,). Do I have to make two graphs of shape=[None] and shape=[None, None] respectively, or is there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

**Placeholder tensors:**

As far as I know, `tf.placeholder` creates a placeholder tensor into the default `tf.Graph` object. A `placeholder` tensor basically **creates a pathway/entrance** for values to enter the graph. They act as inputs to a graph which may correspond to a model too.
The values ( not belonging to the graph ) are fed to the placeholders using the `feed_dict` mentioned by you.

**`tf.convert_to_tensor()`** :

As mentioned in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor),

> This function converts Python objects of various types to Tensor
>   objects. It accepts Tensor objects, numpy arrays, Python lists, and
>   Python scalars.

It converts an existing NumPy array or Python object to a corresponding tensor ( with same dtype and shape ). This tensor will not be a placeholder tensor. It's just a utility to convert NumPy arrays and create `tf.Tensor` objects out of them.

Hence, placeholder tensors allow you feed NumPy arrays or Python objects directly to the graph using `feed_dict`. If your data is static then you can include it in the graph by creating a tensor out of it using `tf.convert_to_tensor()`.